# CSV LOADER ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, data-mining, weka

I am trying to upload a CSV file and getting the following error:

```
weka csv loader failed to load csv file
Wrong number of values. Read 2, expected 5, read token[EOL], line 3
```

This is a sample of my data:

```
1439,"@shanli4m sagen wirs so ich bin fuer ALLE andern AUSSER SPANIEN hahahhaah :-)",219886226486992900,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.079310","2012-07-08 08:17:40.141548"
1440,"ich bin für schland=schland verliert ich bin für italien=italien verliert verkehrte welt -,-",219727870568824830,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.145610","2012-07-08 08:17:40.148478" 
1441,"RT @orbisclaudiae: ""Ich bin für Spanien, weil ich finde, dass die besser aussehen."" (Claudia H., 29, Fußballexpertin)",219544383773618180,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.151433","2012-07-08 08:17:40.153887"
```

Comment: I guess it expects a CSV with 5 fields and only found 2… Could you provide the first 5 lines of your CSV file ?

Comment: 1439,"@shanli4m sagen wirs so ich bin fuer ALLE andern AUSSER SPANIEN hahahhaah :-)",219886226486992900,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.079310","2012-07-08 08:17:40.141548"
1440,"ich bin für schland=schland verliert
ich bin für italien=italien verliert

verkehrte welt -,-",219727870568824830,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.145610","2012-07-08 08:17:40.148478"
1441,"RT @orbisclaudiae: ""Ich bin für Spanien, weil ich finde, dass die besser aussehen."" (Claudia H., 29, Fußballexpertin)",219544383773618180,"2012-07-08 08:17:40.151433","2012-07-08 08:17:40.153887"

Comment: These are tweets from Twitter that I have stored in the database.

Comment: I edited your post to make it more clear. Next time, instead of adding data in a comment, you might want to edit your post yourself if you have new information relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to a problem in the 3rd line:

```
"RT @orbisclaudiae: ""Ich bin für Spanien
```

As you can see before 'Ich' there are two double quotes `""`. This closes the first part (`"RT @orbisclaudiae: "`) and Weka expects a comma (`,`) or the end of the line. Since it is not followed by a comma, Weka assumes that the line is finished and then returns with only 2 values instead of 5. So to fix this, check your data for any inconsistencies like multiple double quotes. You might easily fix this by surrounding the tweets in single quotes (`'`). Weka will most likely consider everything within the single quote as 1 string.

Comment: The problem is indeed here, because some implementations of csv parsers escapes quotes characters by doubling them, and it seems weka csv parser does not.